# Flutter: How to convert base64 to image?

Tags: flutter, base64

I've sent a message in JSON format and I can show the data as Base64 but I don't know how to convert it to an image and show it.

```
class _ShowformState extends State<Showform> {
  List data;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Maintenancce Information", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 13)),),
      body: _buildListView(),);}
  Widget _buildListView() {
    return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: data == null ? 0 : data.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return _buildColumnInfo(data[index]);
        }); }
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    this.getJSONData();}

Future<String> getJSONData() async {
    var url = "http://192.168.1.35:7000/";
    var response = await http.get(url);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var jsonResponse = json.decode(utf8.decode(response.bodyBytes));
      setState(() {
        data = jsonResponse['data'];});
      var itemCount = jsonResponse['totalItems'];}

  Widget _buildColumnInfo(item) {
    return new Container(
            padding: new EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
            child: new Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Text("Data Inserted : ${item['photoBase64']}"),], ),)}}
```

What methods do I need to decode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this code:

```
Uint8List convertBase64Image(String base64String) {
  return Base64Decoder().convert(base64String.split(',').last);
}
```

And add to your UI:

```
Image.memory(
  convertBase64Image(item['photoBase64']),
  gaplessPlayback: true,
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple below code is for convert base64 to Image :

```
Image.memory(base64.decode(base64String.split(',').last))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't convert direct base64 to Image but you can display image like below.

```
Uint8List bytes= base64.decode("${item['photoBase64']}");
```

In UI

```
Image.memory(
        bytes,
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
   );
```