# Flutter how to display an image from base64

Tags: flutter, image, dart, base64

I am using an API that brings data like this:

```
"photos": [
    {
      "id": 6,
      "name": "Seguridad",
      "base64Image": "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD...",
    }
]
```

What I need to do is to display the photos in a screen in my App. I've searched how to do it but I kept having the same error message: Exception: Invalid Image Data. I've read that what I need to do is to encode my base64 String, then decode that and then use it on Image.Memory, like this:

```
String image = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD...';
var bs64 = base64.encode(utf8.encode(example));
Uint8List decodedImage = base64.decode(bs64);
// --------
Image.memory(decodedImage)
```

I've tried using different base64 strings but the error is always there. I appreciate any help with this.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you need to encode here (`base64.encode(utf8.encode(example));`)? The `String image` is not a base64 image, but a [data URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URLs) that contains a base64 image. The base64 part starts after "base64,". So just cut off everthing before "/9j/..." before you decode it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter: How to convert base64 to image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64678844/flutter-how-to-convert-base64-to-image)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

Because you are not decoding `base64` string.

You have to remove `data:image/jpeg;base64,` (comma included)

you have to remove that because that `data:image/jpeg;base64,` just indicates that the string is image data with jpeg format which is encoded as `base64` string.

So, the actual `base64` data starts after it and you have to decode that.

Comment: You're absolutely right. If we display it with `Image.memory` then we just need "plain" base64. Thanks!